# Excel WorkbookRange always empty using Microsoft Graph SDK v5

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm struggling with reading data out of an Excel Worksheet after upgrading to Microsoft Graph .NET SDK to v5.

This code is working with v4 of the SDK:

```
WorkbookRange range = await client.Me
    .Drive.Items[bookId]
    .Workbook.Worksheets[tabId]
    .Range("A1:XX1")
    .Request()
    .GetAsync(cancellation)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

var data = range.Text.Deserialize<List<List<string>>>()!;
```

After moving to v5, I am able to get the range, but `Text` is always empty:

```
WorkbookRange? used = await client
    .Drives["Me"].Items[bookId]
    .Workbook.Worksheets[tabId]
    .UsedRangeWithValuesOnly(true)
    .GetAsync(cancellationToken: cancellation)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

WorkbookRange? range = await client
    .Drives["Me"].Items[bookId]
    .Workbook.Worksheets[tabId]
    .RangeWithAddress("A1:XX1")
    .GetAsync(cancellationToken: cancellation)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

How do I get data from these ranges?

Comment: Is `Values` also empty or only `Text`?

Comment: `Values` is also empty.

Comment: Be empty do you mean it is null?

Comment: Its a `Json` object with no content. Its not null.

Comment: I can confirm the same behavior. I've created a bug for it: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1783

Comment: Still the case with nuget version 5.6.0

Comment: Still the case with nuget version 5.11.0